# rabbitmq-server start failed with exitcode 1

Tags: rabbitmq, cloud, openstack

I am trying to install open stack with pack stack using liberty  on a single node on Centos7  it failed while trying to start rabbit mq-server with the 
following error:
unable to connect to epmd (port 4369) on www: timeout (timed out)
I opened all the ports related to rabbitmq-server like 4369,5672, but no luck
Execution of '/usr/bin/systemctl start rabbitmq-server' returned 1
any help greatly appreciated

Thank you so much for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ server fails if hostname does not match with hostname in /etc/hosts with hostname in /etc/hostname file ,

make sure you  declare hosts like

ip                fully qualified domain name               hostname 
---               --------------------------              -------------

x.x.x.x              example.com                            subdomain